# Is there any word for the rocks used to pave paths near a medieval home?

Tags: word-request

Is there any word for the rocks used to pave paths near a medieval home? I was thinking of ***pebbles***, but I am not sure if there exists a specific word for *the rocks used to pave path during the medieval age*, or if there are other kinds of rocks that were used during that time other than pebbles, which is very generic and not specific enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may be thinking of ***cobbles*** or ***cobblestones***:

> A naturally rounded stone (usually from rivers, fields or the sea) used for paving and walls. Setts are often popularly called cobbles. They are small stones or pebbles that were traditionally gathered from stream beds and hence had been rounded and smoothed by water. ([designing buildings](https://www.designingbuildings.co.uk/wiki/Cobble))

This [Sunwood site](https://www.sunwooddevelopment.com/building-blog-ct/the-history-of-cobblestones-and-their-use-in-paving-for-your-connecticut-home) states that they have been around since long before the Middle Ages:

> As early as 238 B.C.E., the Romans used tons and tons of cobblestones to create 50,000 miles of roads linking every part of the Roman Empire together—and they all lead to Rome!

They can look like that:

[image]

(The picture is called "Dinan, traditional colorful houses on a cobbled street in medieval town center, Brittany, France" from [Shutterstock.com](https://www.shutterstock.com/image-photo/dinan-traditional-colorful-houses-on-cobbled-1310426644))

or like that:

[image]

(Cobblestone streets and old buildings in Sighisoara Medieval Fortress, Romania from [Shutterstock.com](https://www.shutterstock.com/image-photo/sighisoara-romania-1126-cobblestone-streets-old-1878548107) again)

Note that

> While ***cobblestones*** and ***setts*** look similar, they're not quite the same. The main difference is the shape. Paving setts are cut into uniform square sizes while cobbles keep their natural rounded shape. As a result, setts have a finish that complements modern spaces. ([simplypaving.com](https://www.simplypaving.com/products/paving/carpet-stones-and-setts/))

Comment: Flagstones would be possible, but near most homes cobblestones would be more likely.

Comment: They’re very popular in (Western) European cities. They look lovely and are more resistant to freezing weather (potholes) but they’re not great for driving on. :)

Comment: You'd better watch your steps when walking on them, too :) ! Such streets can be uneven and slippery!